# What does errno=13 mean when connecting via OpenVPN?

Tags: permissions, sudo, openvpn

The tail-end of an OpenVPN connection (that otherwise appears successful) says (with leading timestamps omitted):

Note: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: Permission denied (errno=13)
Note: Attempting fallback to kernel 2.2 TUN/TAP interface
Cannot allocate TUN/TAP dev dynamically
Exiting

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface you OpenVPN command (line) with sudo...

i.e. the command requires root access to operate successfully

Comment: Do not forget to give execute permission to the resolv update script if you have one, i.e. `sudo chmod +x /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` as it causes the same error #13.